# Can someone please help identify this plant?

Tags: identification

Here is a photo of the plant I wish to have identified

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's an epiphytic fern called [Asplenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asplenium), possibly [*Asplenium nidus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asplenium_nidus).